# The stopping point in while loop in python

Tags: python

```
i=0
>>> while i<3:
...     print i
...     i += 1
... else:
...     print ‘Done with i =’, i
...
0
1
2
Done with i = 3
```

Hi all, I am wondering why the while loop is done when i=3, not when i=2. When i=2, i=i+1=2+1=3, the expression becomes False, then execution gets finished. Isn't that right?

Comment: Huh?  Like you said, when i is 2, it will check, print 2, and then increment i to 3.  It will then check again and this time the check will be false and so it will quit the while loop, and since you didn't break out, the else will fire with i set to 3.

Comment: My thought is new_i = old_i + 1, and when old_i is 2,  new_i becomes 3 and the loop finished, so i should be 2( the old one).

Answer (score 3):

The `else` in a `while ... else` block always executes.  So your `while` loop ends with `i == 2`, but then you increment with `i += 1`, so `i == 3`.  Then your `while` loop quits, and you perform the `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

That `else` block will always execute. It's the same as simply writing `print "Done with i =", i`. As BlivetWidget said, you are adding 1 to `i` and then executing the else block. Instead, you could use `print "Done with i = ", i-1`.